# Can't create foreign key with ON DELETE SET DEFAULT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I can't create foreign keys with `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`, but if i use `ON DELETE CASCADE` then all works here is my sql

```
CREATE TABLE person(  
    customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
    name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE 
);


CREATE TABLE habits(  
    customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
    habit VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE 
);

INSERT INTO `test`.`habits` (`customer_id`, `habit`) VALUES (NULL, 'smoking'), (NULL, 'drinking');
INSERT INTO `test`.`person` (`customer_id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, 'John'), (NULL, 'Steve');

CREATE TABLE foreigner(  
    customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
    customer VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'John', 
    habbit  VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'smoking', 
    FOREIGN KEY (customer) REFERENCES person(name)  ON DELETE SET DEFAULT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (habbit) REFERENCES habits(habit)  ON DELETE SET DEFAULT ON UPDATE CASCADE     
);
```

It's strange that it works if I use `ON DELETE CASCADE`.... any thoughts?

Comment: So, instead of 5 (or any olther number of) rows to be deleted from the `foreigner` table (due to cascading effects), you want to end up with five (almost) identical rows with `(customer,habbit) = ('John,'smoking')`. Why would you want that?

Comment: And I couldn't resist mentioning the 3 useless `customer_id` columns.

Comment: the table with those values is just an example - in reality I have  much larger tables with values and rows that might even be useful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)...

> SET DEFAULT: This action is recognized by the parser, but InnoDB rejects table
>   definitions containing ON DELETE SET DEFAULT or ON
>   UPDATE SET DEFAULT clauses.

You could try SET NULL, but I'm not sure if that will cause you other problems instead.

Comment: Thanks I tried  ON DELETE SET NULL and it worked. I guess will have to stick with that.. if InnoDB doesn't support ON DELETE SET DEFAULT, which engine would support it with foreign keys together with ON UPDATE CASCADE?