# Question about ON DELETE SET DEFAULT. Does the default value need to exist in the referenced table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
    ProdID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(100,5),
    ProdName VARCHAR(20)
)
```

Then I insert some rows:

```
INSERT INTO Products VALUES ('Coat Rack') --Will be given a ProdID of 100
INSERT INTO Products VALUES ('Coffee Table') --Will be given a ProdID of 105
```

Then I create another table called Orders that has a FK constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
   OrderID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(800,2),
   ProductID INT DEFAULT 0,
   CONSTRAINT fk_ProdID FOREIGN KEY(ProductID) REFERENCES Products(ProdID) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
)
```

Notice the ProductID column has a default value of 0, and a FK constraint that specifies the ON DELETE SET DEFAULT setting.

Then insert one row:

```
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (105) --Row references the "Coffee Table" product.
```

If I try to delete the product "Coffee Table" from the Products table, I get a message saying the product can't be deleted because it's referenced in the Orders table. I understand it is, but I was expecting the FK constraint to simply allow the row to be deleted, then put 0 in the referencing row. 0 is of course the default value for the referencing column (ProductID), and the FK constraint specifies ON DELETE SET DEFAULT.

So with ON DELETE SET DEFAULT, does the default value still need to exist in the referenced table?

Seems a bit odd to me if that's the case. One would probably want to create a "dummy" row in the referenced table, and set the default value equal to whatever ID is used for that dummy row. We'd do this so that if we delete a product, any referencing rows would point to that dummy product instead of an ACTUAL product

Comment: The foreign key constraint must still be satisfied with the default value. You could use `SET NULL` instead but I think one would want orders to contain only valid products.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881424/cant-create-foreign-key-with-on-delete-set-default

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman. Was just looking for verification.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation

> **SET DEFAULT**
>
> All the values that comprise the foreign key are set to their default values when the corresponding row in the parent table is deleted. For this constraint to execute, all foreign key columns must have default definitions. If a column is nullable and there is no explicit default value set, NULL becomes the implicit default value of the column.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

What it does not explain very well indeed is that the default value **MUST EXIST** in the parent table. If not, you got the error of constraint violation.

A way to show you this based on your example

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
    ProdID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(100,5),
    ProdName VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
   OrderID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(800,2),
   ProductID INT DEFAULT 0,
   CONSTRAINT fk_ProdID FOREIGN KEY(ProductID) REFERENCES Products(ProdID) 
   ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
)

INSERT INTO Products VALUES ('Coat Rack') --Will be given a ProdID of 100
INSERT INTO Products VALUES ('Coffee Table') --Will be given a ProdID of 105

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Products ON; -- Enable to insert default dummy product 
INSERT INTO Products (ProdID, ProdName) VALUES ( 0 , 'Dummy') -- Insert dummy product

INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (105) --Row references the "Coffee Table" product. 

DELETE FROM Orders where ProductID = 105
```

A complete demo of you code in dbfiddle

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f754979d3aa4d01b12a80a0c359b314f)